# Intro to Classical Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

I am having trouble understanding page 53, of *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*, by Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen.

**Corollary 3.** $$(-1)^{(p-1)/2} = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$$  Where the right-hand side is the Legendre symbol.

The part I'm tripping over is the next paragraph, which states: Corollary 3 is interesting.  Every odd integer has the form $4k + 1$ or $4k + 3$.  (I understand that).  Using this, one can restate the corollary as:

$$x^{2}\equiv -1\bmod(p)\text{ has a solution} \iff p \text{ is of the form } 4k + 1$$

How did the authors go from the corollary to the restatement?

Comment: Just use the definition of $(-1/p)$ and look for $(p-1)/2$ in the exponent modulo $4$, i.e., $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ or $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$, for $p>2$.

Comment: It follows from $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ being cyclic with $p-1$ elements, so $-1 \equiv g^{(p-1)/2} \bmod p$ with $p$ a generator and we need $(p-1)/2$ even to obtain $-1 \equiv (g^{(p-1)/4})^2 \bmod p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the Legendre symbol? By definition $(\frac{-1}{p})=1$ if $(-1)$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, otherwise $(\frac{-1}{p})=-1$. Now the statement says that $(\frac{-1}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$. Now it is easy to check that if $p$ has the form $4k+1$ then $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is even and hence by the statement $(\frac{-1}{p})=1$, which means $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$. On the other hand if $p$ has the form $4k+3$ then $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd and hence $(\frac{-1}{p})=-1$, so in that case $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The congruence has a solution iff the Legendre symbol is equal to $1$ which is the case iff the power of $-1$ in the explicit formula for the Legendre symbol is even.